# Polynomials - rational root - divisibility

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

This is a simple (almost obvious) question but I somehow cannot find an elementary solution yet.
$$f(x) = a_0x^n + a_1x^{n-1} + ... + a_{n-1}x + a_n$$
is a polynomial with integer coefficients.

$$\frac{p}{q}$$ is a rational root of $f(x)$,
where $p,q$ are whole numbers and $(p,q) = 1$

**Prove that $(p-mq)$ | $f(m)$ for every whole number $m$**

Assume the solution has to be explained to someone in 7th or 8th grade
i.e. one who doesn't know much about any complicated theory of polynomials.

E.g. I know that $f(x)$ can be written as $$a_0\left(x-\frac{p}{q}\right)R(x)$$
where $R(x)$ is a polynomial but can I claim $R(x)$ has integer
coefficients. If I can, then the desired statement follows easily, it seems.
But why can I claim this?

Note: you can assume I (or the student to whom I must explain this)
know that $p/a_n$ and $q/a_0$, this was proved already.

At some point I thought of using induction (on $m$) but that
seems somewhat complicated and I don't know if it will work at all.

Comment: I am somewhat confused by the fact that the $x^k$ term doesn't have $a_k$ as coefficient.

Comment: @Arthur OK, well... that's how it's in my book. Doesn't matter. You can let $b_k = a_{n-k}$

Comment: Note that the book offers no solution or even hint for this statement :)

Comment: This is a less used, imo, notation for polynomials. I think most authors would prefer nowadays to write down polynomials where the index of each coefficient mathces the power of $\;x\;$ . This is specially easier to grasp for high school students.

Comment: @DonAntonio I don't know, I've been taught about polynomials with this "reverse" notation and this book also uses it. It doesn't really matter.

Comment: Your polynomial $R$ does not have integer coefficients in general.

Comment: (The notation doesn't matter, I've seen a few algebraic number theorists use this convention. Sometimes it is more convenient.)

Comment: *to someone in 7th or 8th grade* --- In the USA this would probably be 10th or 11th grade, and then only for more advanced students (at most probably upper 30% of all students)!

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I don't know, I am not in the USA :) I was taught this kind of problems in 8th grade or so in preparation for competitions. Sorry, yeah, I meant how to explain it from someone in high school?!

Comment: Yes, I know. I checked your profile before writing my comment. I was curious whether you were from another country or whether you were perhaps an advanced USA student (or teach advanced USA students) writing a bit imprecisely (i.e. as if "everyone" is this advanced at 7th or 8th grade). Both situations seem to occur here often . . . (Sorry, but I don't have time now to look at the question you're asking, as I'm about to leave for the gym.)

Comment: @QiZhu OK, yeah, $R(x)$ indeed does not have integer coefficients in general. Simple example: $f(x) = 15x^2 - 11x + 2$ and $p=2, q=5$

Comment: Much simpler: $4x^2 - 1$. :)

Comment: another example: $f(x) = 4x^2-1$, $p/q = 1/2$, $f(x) = 4(x-1/2)(x+1/2)$

Comment: OK... well, I will go continue to think on this problem myself. There should be some sort of simple solution here. Thanks so much for you looking into it too.

Comment: An idea : induction on the degree $n$ of $f$. Put $g(x)=q^nf(x)-a_0 (qx-p)^n$ then the degree of $g$ is $<$ degree of $f$. By the induction hypothesis, for all $m$ , $p-qm$ divide $g(m)$, hence $q^n f(m)$. But $p-qm$ is prime to $q$, hence to $q^n$...

Comment: I wrote a detailed elementary proof below. Could someone check please if there's some flaw it in or it really works? It kind of uses the general idea by @Kelenner

Answer (score 1):

How about this solution?

We will use induction on $n$ (the degree of $f$)
for the statement we are trying to prove which is

**$(p-mq)$ | $f(m)$ for every whole number $m$**

The base case $n=1$ is very easy. So let's assume we have this already.

We know that $q\ |\ a_0 \tag{1}$

So let's denote $a_0 = q \cdot c_0 \tag{2}$

Note that $c_0$ is a whole number (as are all $a_i$).

OK... then we get:

$$f(x) = a_0x^n + a_1x^{n-1} + ... + a_{n-1}x + a_n = $$

$$ = c_0 q x^n + a_1x^{n-1} + ... + a_{n-1}x + a_n = $$

$$ = (xq - p) c_0 x^{n-1} + (a_1 + pc_0)x^{n-1} + a_2 x^{n-2} + ... + a_{n-1} x + a_n \tag{3}$$

Now we know that $p/q$ is a root of $f(x)$ and obviously it is also a root of the first term $(xq - p) c_0 x^{n-1}$ from the sum above.

So $p/q$ must also be a root of

$$h(x) = (a_1 + pc_0)x^{n-1} + a_2 x^{n-2} + ... + a_{n-1} x + a_n$$

But this polynomial $h(x)$ is of degree $(n-1)$ so we can apply the induction hypothesis. From it we get that $$(p-mq)\ |\ h(m) \tag{4}$$ for every whole number $m$.

But then from (3) we can see that $$f(m) = (mq - p) \cdot m^{n-1} + h(m) \tag{5}$$
for every whole number $m$.

And then from (4) and (5), we obtain that
**$(p-mq)$ divides also $f(m)$ for every whole number $m$**.

Is this proof good enough? Or does this proof have some subtle flaw?

If it's good enough, then the statement is indeed easy because everything was straightforward in the induction that we did, and we used just the fact that $q\ |\ a_0$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $R = x^{n-1} + \dots + b_{1}x + b_{0}$, then $$ f = a_0 \left(x - \frac{p}{q} \right) R = a_0 x^n + \left(a_0 b_{n-2} - a_0 \frac{p}{q} \right) x^{n-1} + \left(a_0 b_{n-3} - \frac{p}{q} \right) x^{n-2} + \dots + \left(-a_0 b_0 \frac{p}{q} \right).$$ So $a_0 b_{n-k} - a_0 \frac{p}{q} \in \mathbb{Z}$. Thus, the $a_0 b_{n-k} \in \frac{1}{q} \mathbb{Z}$. On the other hand, $\operatorname{gcd}(q,p-mq) = 1$, so since $a_0 R \in \frac{1}{q} \mathbb{Z}[x]$, your desired result follows.

Comment: I will need to digest this a bit. Thanks, will reread this a few more times, and see if I can understand it.

Comment: What is $b_k$ here? Is it what I suggested $b_k = a_{n-k}$ ?

Comment: @peter.petrov Those are just the coefficients of the polynomial $R$. Sorry, I didn't see that you used the notation $b$ in the comments already.